# Sound duration in android app

Tags: android, audio

I'm making a small android app. When a button in the app pressed, a sound starts. The audio file's duration is about 30 ms. But when I run it on my AVD and press the button, it's crashed.
Could you tell me why?
Thanks.

Comment: Post the stacktrace of the failure. You can't fix a problem if you don't know what is causing the application to crash (generally the easiest issues to diagnose)

Comment: Also it's not "normal" to play a 0.030 duration of sound. Is it MP3? Anyways at least try making it a full 1 second (fill remaining 0.970 space with silence) and from those decoded 1000 millisecs you could then extract & play the 30 millisecs. Might be easier for your system to crunch the numbers if has at least 1 second of data to calculate from...